# Nginx check multiple directories, if file exist redirect to that directory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Use something like `try_files` how can I check multiple directories to see if a file exist? If file exist redirect to that location if not display 404.

old folder `^/wp-content/uploads(/.*)?$`

**multiple folders to check**

```
/sites/default/files$1;
/sites/default/files/testA$1;
/sites/default/files/testB$1;
/sites/default/files/testC$1;
/sites/default/files/testD$1;
```

ex: if file is present in `/sites/default/files/testB$1;` then rewrite `^/wp-content/uploads(/.*)?$` to that location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably easiest to do with multiple `if` blocks, but [read this first](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), because you should only use statements like `rewrite ... last` or `return` inside an `if` block.

Something like this might work for you:

```
location ~ ^/wp-content/uploads(?<name>/.*)?$ {
    if (-f $document_root/sites/default/files$name) {
        return 301 /sites/default/files$name;
    }
    if (...) { ... }
    if (...) { ... }
    if (...) { ... }
    if (...) { ... }
    return 404;
}
```

You need to position the `location` block above other regular expression `location` blocks, that might conflict with it. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

EDIT: Maybe it looks better as parameters to a `try_files` directive. I don't know if there is an upper limit on the size of a `try_files` statement:

```
location ~ ^/wp-content/uploads(?<name>/.*)?$ {
    try_files
        /sites/default/files$name
        /sites/default/author_images$name
        /sites/default/blog_images$name
        ...
        =404;
}
```

You may need to experiment with the final `?` in the regular expression. Do you want the URI `/wp-content/uploads` to match the location?

Comment: does this look about right to you... starting at line 48? https://gist.github.com/devGOD/479f0034ad92335eaa0f1c27697a7088

Comment: Should line 40 take precedence over line 48? Or do you need to reverse those blocks? Otherwise, looks fine.

Comment: Line 40 may need to be after... thanks

Comment: can this been rewritten with `try_files`?

Comment: I have added an EDIT - but the answer is yes.

Comment: The URI `/wp-content/uploads` needs to match the location. it does not change just the file name

Comment: I updated my gist following your format.